# Build dependency libraries with same compiler options as applications

Tags: windows, rust-cargo

I'm writing Rust bindings for a cross-platform C++ library and I'm having problems building my example applications on Windows that consume this library as a dependency, because there's a mismatch in the debug settings between the application and the dependency.

Specifically, the error I'm getting is `error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in {libfile}`, which I can avoid if I compile my example app with `--release` config, as it matches what the dependency is being built with.

Is there a way I can force dependency libraries to be built with the same settings as the main application, ideally in a way that's completely transparent to the user?

I tried looking for some rustc flags that could help me here, but I couldn't find anything relevant: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#rustc-flags